# Amazon RTMP stream serving cached media file

Tags: amazon-web-services, rtmp

I am using Amazon RTMP distribution for serving video. But I found a cache issue.

I have uploaded the file 'abc.mp4' in a bucket that RTMP distribution will use. After that I replaced that file with an updated video file with the same name (i.e 'abc.mp4'). But RTMP is showing me the same previous video file.

As I have seen, there is no cache setting while creating RTMP distribution.

Has anybody faced the same issue? Please help me find a solution.

Thanks.